# Why is my Python REGEX findall returning an unexpected list of matches?

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to detect the following pattern:
even number of `\` followed by `$` and text.

This is valid: `\\$hello` or `$goodbye`.

I am trying to do this in Python:

```
txt = r"\\$hello"
regex = r"(?<!\\)(\\\\)*(?!\\)\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*"

x = re.findall(regex, txt)

if x:
  print(x)
else:
  print("No match")
```

When I run this, I get this output `['\\\\']` even though when I try it here: https://regex101.com/, I get a full match of `\\$hello`. How can I adjust this to get the entire portion to get matched? Or even better, just the part without the slashes?

Other things I've tried:

1. Remote escaping characters in regex: `r"(?<!\)(\\\)*(?!\)\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*"` This leads to error `re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 11`

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I am pretty sure that in raw expressions, \ doesn't need to be escaped. My text input is correct. It can be written like this: `"\\\\$hello"` or `r"\\$hello"`. Both means the same thing (two slashes followed by $hello).

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the idea behind your regex, so I cannot really say where you went wrong. But the following works with your verbal description of the matching pattern ("an even number of backslashes, followed by a dollar sign, followed by text") and retrieves the text after the `$` sign:

```py
import re


txt = r"\\$hello"
regex = r"(\\)*\$(.*)"
match = re.findall(regex,txt)[0][1]
```

If you want the dollar sign included in the matchstring, just adapt:

```py
regex = r"(\\)*(\$.*)"
```